# Laravel get file name from folder with File method

Tags: php, file, laravel-5, filenames

Cant figure out how to get `file name` from folder in ````filePath```

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

    $filePath = storage_path('app/apiFiles/'.auth()->user()->id_message.'/');

    $fileName = File::files($filePath);

    dd($fileName);
```

`dd($fileName)` return array but i need only `filename` is possible to separated from array?

what i need from array is only this `filename: "Z1iZ03gEhltPZj2Z2Rxnnuga2eXywheL4pQc5q0I.zip"`

```
 array:1 [▼
    0 => Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo {#293 ▼
    -relativePath: ""
    -relativePathname: "Z1iZ03gEhltPZj2Z2Rxnnuga2eXywheL4pQc5q0I.zip"
    path: "/var/www/html/domain/storage/app/apiFiles/910960"
    filename: "Z1iZ03gEhltPZj2Z2Rxnnuga2eXywheL4pQc5q0I.zip"
    basename: "Z1iZ03gEhltPZj2Z2Rxnnuga2eXywheL4pQc5q0I.zip"
    pathname: "/var/www/html/domain/storage/app/apiFiles/910960/Z1iZ03gEhltPZj2Z2Rxnnuga2eXywheL4pQc5q0I.zip"
    extension: "zip"
    realPath: "/var/www/html/domain/storage/app/apiFiles/910960/Z1iZ03gEhltPZj2Z2Rxnnuga2eXywheL4pQc5q0I.zip"
   aTime: 2020-10-22 06:46:37
   mTime: 2020-10-22 06:46:37
   cTime: 2020-10-22 06:46:37
   inode: 1308192
   size: 3180822
   perms: 0100644
   owner: 33
   group: 33
   type: "file"
   writable: true
   readable: true
   executable: false
   file: true
   dir: false
   link: false
 }
```

]

Comment: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;`
`$files = Storage::files($directory);`

Will it work?

Comment: @SiddharajsinhZala ````dd($files)```` return empty ````[]````

Comment: is it possible that the folder has multiple files?

Comment: @SiddharajsinhZala only one file ````Z1iZ03gEhltPZj2Z2Rxnnuga2eXywheL4pQc5q0I.zip````

Comment: Then you can check whether the array is empty or not? If it is not empty, then get the file name from [0] index. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution, wierd but its enough for my project

```
 $filePath = storage_path('app/Files/'.auth()->user()->id_message.'/');
```

`dd($filePath)`return -> `/var/www/html/domain/storage/app/apiFiles/910960/`

in directory `910960` is one file only `hash.zip`

get name of file from directory:

```
$fileNameArray = preg_grep("~\.(zip)$~", scandir($filePath));
```

`dd($fileNameArray)` return -> array with `"Z1iZ03gEhltPZj2Z2Rxnnuga2eXywheL4pQc5q0I.zip"`

last step is convert array to string:

```
$fileNameString = implode("", $fileNameArray);
```